# How to load Custom cell (Xib) in UITableview using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, xcode6

Here's my code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return 10   
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell :UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("discovered") as UITableViewCell!

    bluetoothlog.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "devicedet", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "discovered")
    //NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("devicedet", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as UITableViewCell

    cell = blucell
    devname.text = peri[indexPath.row]
    devstrength.text = signalstrength[indexPath.row]

    bluetoothlog.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell        
}
```

I have tried with the above code and  nothing is displayed in Tableview, please help me to change this code working

Thanks

Comment: Please reformat your code it is hard to read atm!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //MARK:- Sample Data Array to load in TableView
        let sampleArrray: \[String\] = \["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5"]

    //MARK:- Cell reuse identifier 
        let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"


    //MARK:- UITableView outlet 
         @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

          override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Registering the custom cell

            self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

            // Setting delegate and Datasourse as same viewcontroller (this code is not neccessory if we are setting it from storyboard)

            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }
    //UITableview required methods 

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return sampleArrray.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

            cell.textLabel?.text = sampleArrray\[indexPath.row\]

            return cell
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           print("clicked at: \(indexPath.row)")
           //Here u can get the selected cell and add action related to this cell seelction 
        }
```

Added Screenshot for setting Datasource and delegate from storyboard
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Register your NIB with the reuse identifier:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "devicedet", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   }
   ```
2. Your cellForRowAtIndexPath would then instantiate the cell.

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! devicedet

       return cell
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    var cell :devicedet = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("discovered") as UITableViewCell!

    bluetoothlog.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "devicedet", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "discovered")
    //NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("devicedet", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as UITableViewCell

    cell = blucell
    devname.text = peri[indexPath.row]
    devstrength.text = signalstrength[indexPath.row]

    bluetoothlog.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell        
}
```

Comment: If Still you don't get the Desired output. Then add your bluetoothlog.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "devicedet", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "discovered")
 in ViewDidLoad() and remove from your current method.

Comment: Tried with your code then....
Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key blucell.'

Comment: what's the name of your customcell .h and .m file name . Create instance of that class .

Comment: Bluetooth ViewController1.swift

Comment: Why didn't you post the code under your other answer?

Comment: var cell : Bluetooth ViewController1= tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("discovered") as Bluetooth ViewController1

Answer (score 1):

- the command registerNib should be called in ViewDidLoad, but not in each call of cell for row
- what is 'bluecell'? In your call-back cellforTable.., you assign cell = blucell -> this can cause your problems.

Try this:

```
import UIKit

class YourViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//call register nib here!!
        bluetoothlog.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "devicedet", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "discovered")
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return peri.count    
}

//it seem that you have to add a è
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell :UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("discovered") as UITableViewCell!
/*  REMOVE THIS
    bluetoothlog.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "devicedet", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "discovered")
    //NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("devicedet", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as UITableViewCell
*/
  //// THEN, UPDATE YOUR CELL with YOUR DATAs

/* I don't understand what are you doing with this line of code:
    cell = blucell

*/

    devname.text = peri[indexPath.row]
    devstrength.text = signalstrength[indexPath.row]

//Seem that bluetoothlog is the tableview, you should call it in viewdidload or viewwillappear()
    bluetoothlog.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell        
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad register XIB as shown below

```
var userDetailsNIB = UINib(nibName: "UserDetailsCell", bundle: nil)
        viewListingTable.registerNib(userDetailsNIB, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UserDetailsViewCellID")

And in func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

function use it by access it with Identifier which created in viewDidLoad method

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserDetailsViewCellID") as UserDetailsViewCell

return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to Load custom cell(Xib) in UITableView in swift ,you may use the following code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count; //This function returns number of rows in table view
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:YourTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourTableViewCell", forIndexPath:indexPath)as! YourTableViewCell
   // Do additional code here
}
```

Don’t forget to register nib in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // registering your nib
    let yourNibName = UINib(nibName: "YourTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(yourNibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourTableViewCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register `xib` Cell in Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "XibCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.register(
         UINib(nibName: "XibCell", bundle: nil), 
         forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell"
     )
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
               cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") 
    return cell as! UITableViewCell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your fuction registerNib , you try to write in viewDidLoad() method and remove from cellForRowAtIndexPah and then test your project

Your Cell Instance should be of CustomCell instance and not of UITableView Cell.
var cell :UITableViewCell should be replaced by 
var cell :devicedet

Comment: Without registering the cell the app will crash while loading the view