# Swift: how to make custom tableview from xib files? 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must translate autoresizing mask?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Alright, I need to know the correct way to do this - I have made custom tableviews with custom cells using storyboard and normal VC class files, however now I need to do it with a ViewController class linked to a xib file and I am failing.

Ive gotten several different errors but now I am left with

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.'

This is what Ive done - 
I made my class with a xib file and dragged a tableview into it. I connected the tableview and added all the needed functions in my class. Also set the delegate and datasource -

```
class EventsAddedToViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "EventsAddedCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "addedCell")
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return  screenSize.height * (61/screenSize.height) //has to be same as bottom tab - 61
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, RETURN NUMBER OF SECTIONS
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, RETURN THE NUMBER OF ROWS
//        if names.count < dates.count {
//            return names.count
//        } else {
//            return dates.count
//        }
        return 100
    }

    //cell work IMPORTANT
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsAddedCell

        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 0)
        if (cell.respondsToSelector("preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins")){
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Again, this is the xib file that was created with my class.

I then needed to add a custom cell to the tableview so I tried to drag one into my tableview but it wouldn't let me. I then looked at [How to load Custom cell (Xib) in UITableview using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432834/how-to-load-custom-cell-xib-in-uitableview-using-swift) and made a separate xib and class file just for the cell:

[image]

I gave it the right reuse identifier "addedCell" that I reference in my overall VC file.

And I am getting a SIGABRT error. What am I doing wrong here?